# Firefox extension Error: Managed storage manifest not found

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, browser-extension, manifest.json

Hello I have a problem with my Firefox Extension, I need to access Managed Storage but get this error while trying to access it :

`Error: Managed storage manifest not found`

Here's my manifest :

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Kabeen",
  "version": "1.1.0",
  "description": "Give feedbacks of your daily apps to your IT team",
  "author": "Kabeen",
  "icons": {
    "48": "assets/img.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.js"
    ],
    "type": "module"
  },
  "browser_specific_settings": {
    "gecko": {
      "id": "storage@kabeen.org"
    }
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "storage",
    "identity"
  ],
  ...
}
```

I'm working on Mac so I create a `Kabeen.json` file in `/Users/my.username/Library/Application Support/Mozilla/ManagedStorage`

Here's the content :

```json
{
  "name": "storage@kabeen.org",
  "description": "ignored",
  "type": "storage",
  "data": {
    "IsIncognito": {
      "title": "Switch extension to incognito mode.",
      "description": "If set to true the popup, dock and satisfaction poll are disabled.",
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "Authentication": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "ApiToken": {
          "title": "Api token to authenticate extension.",
          "description": "If set to true the popup, dock and satisfaction poll are disabled.",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "StructureId": {
          "title": "Structure of the user.",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "TeamId": {
          "title": "Team of the user.",
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Anyone got any idea ?

Thanks for your help :)

I tried to create the json file at the location specified here : [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_manifests)

Comment: Your managed storage manifest is named `Kabeen.json`, but it must be named `storage@kabeen.org.json`, same as the extension ID plus `.json`. The documentation doesn't explicity say this, at least not for managed storage manifests (only for native messaging and PKCS #11 manifests). However, the [favourite-colour](https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/main/favourite-colour) sample extension explicitly mentions this in its README.md file. You're welcome :)